# how do i do a simple loop and JOptionPane in java

Tags: java, loops, joptionpane

I have to take this code and add looping if statements to it and `JOptionPane` so that when you enter a name and number of boxes it just keeps looping and showing the name and number of boxes of who picked the most, until you exit out. But I've fallen behind and I am just simply not sure how to do it and I'm having a lot of trouble with looping.

Here is the code:

```
public class Picker {

    private String name;
    private int numberOfBoxes;
    private int payAmount;
    public static final int PAY_PER_BOX = 3;


    public Picker(String name, int numberOfBoxes) {

        setName(name);
        //this will set the number of boxes and the pay.
        setNumberOfBoxes(numberOfBoxes);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNumberOfBoxes(int numberOfBoxes) {
        this.numberOfBoxes = numberOfBoxes;
        //also set the pay based on the number of boxes.
        payAmount = numberOfBoxes * PAY_PER_BOX;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNumberOfBoxes() {
        return numberOfBoxes;
    }

    public int getPayAmount() {
        return payAmount;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "\n"
                + "Number of boxes: " + numberOfBoxes + "\n"
                + "Pay: $" + payAmount + "\n";

    }

}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PickerTest {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static final String BUSINESS_NAME = "Ham's Blueberry Patch";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create the two pickers
        Picker picker1 = getPicker();
        Picker picker2 = getPicker();

        //Call method to show output
        showSummary(picker1, picker2);
    }

    public static Picker getPicker() {
        //Get picker 1
        System.out.println("Enter name for picker");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter number of boxes");
        int numberOfBoxes = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        Picker picker = new Picker(name, numberOfBoxes);
        return picker;
    }

    public static void showSummary(Picker p1, Picker p2) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(BUSINESS_NAME);
        System.out.println("");
        p1.toString();
        System.out.println("");
        p2.toString();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Total Boxes:  " + (p1.getNumberOfBoxes() + p2.getNumberOfBoxes()));
        System.out.println("Total Pay:  " + (p1.getPayAmount() + p2.getPayAmount()));

    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code **here**, not in a link, and certainly not in an image. For more about the rules and regs of this site, please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions

Comment: do you want me to just copy and paste the code?

Comment: You need to read the links that I've provided above, and they will tell you not what I want, but what the site requires. It's generally a good rule to read all requirements for any new site you post to, not just this one.

Comment: so, in this instance, where i dont know how to loop for this assignment, and dont even know where the code should be, how much code should i be posting?

Comment: so from these images, should i post it all, or cut some out?

Comment: i did but, i dont know where the code should be so im not sure how much to post

Comment: Where's your for loop and JOptionPane attempt code? You stated that it keeps on looping, but I don't see that code, unless I'm missing it.

Comment: i have to add the looping and joptionpane but im not sure how to make it loop, which loop type to use, or how to use joptionpane

Answer (score 1):

You can take help from this code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Hello"); // as parent component is null

        }
```

The above code displays `JOptionPane` three times before exiting. So, you may use the for or while loop according to your requirement.

Comment: so all my inputs need to be joptionpane, so would i just get rid of the scanners and use show input dialog?

Comment: yes.. u can use first frame or Jframe to get the values or u can take values from console also, then iterate according to your requirement.

Comment: the only thing we've done with jOptionPane is show input dialog so can i use that? what do i put in my loop?

Comment: yes you can use JOptionPane.showInputDialog to get input from the user and the use loops. U may use: [link] (http://alvinalexander.com/java/joptionpane-showinputdialog-examples)

Comment: how /where do i write the loop? does it need if else statements?

Answer (score -1):

```
public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + name + "\n"
            + "Number of boxes: " + numberOfBoxes + "\n"
            + "Pay: $" + payAmount + "\n";

}
```

For starters it is a very good idea to put the `@Override` tag above this method, as you are overriding the default toString() method in the Object class. Putting `@Override` will improve the code readability and catch small typos in your method names, and it is a very accepted practice among developers.

Now, assuming I understood your question correct, you can make a `while` loop that runs forever and prints the a pointer's name and amount of boxes. You could store these pointers as a static variable in the `Pointer` class and cycle through them and print based on the highest value. To make it less-spammy, you could store a temporary variable of type `Pointer` or `String` (if you want to store the pointer's name) and if the highest value is equal to that variable don't print anything, otherwise update that temporary variable and print what you want to print based on your values.

Comment: so for the jOptionPane part do i just replace the scanner parts with input dialog? what will go inside of the while loop?

Comment: You could use the JOptionPane as a way to get the input instead of a scanner and then make the while loop that does the behavior I suggested above.

Comment: im not sure how to make it work with input dialog instead of a scanner or how to even write the loop and make it work